# Javascript Image Object - Handle onload Event

Tags: javascript, image, preload

I'm trying to preload image on click event:

```
// new image object
var imgObject = new Image();

// assign the path to the image to the src property
imgObject.src = document.URL + 'image/image.jpg';

// check if image has loaded
if (imgObject.complete) {
```

But the complete call never returns true on the first click - any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.complete` is a property of the image object, not an event that you can attach to. Use the `onload` event:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    alert('image loaded');
};
image.src = document.URL + 'image/image.jpg';
```

**Note:** Be sure to attach to the onload hander before setting the source attribute.

**Note Explanation**: Image caching. If the image is cached then the onload event will fire immediately (sometimes before setting the handler)

Comment: well - I can't really, it has to be on click - and it opens the url taken from the href attribute of the <a> tag - unless I obviously misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: Why is it important to call it before the src property is set?

Comment: Thanks James - it seem to be working now. I'm just wondering why the .complete call didn't work.

Comment: @user398341, `.complete` is a property stating whether the image has been loaded, not an event that you can attach to. Your `if` statement was run immediately after setting the image `src` - it probably would never be true at that point (unless it was cached maybe?). I've updated the answer a little to make that a bit more clear.